# Show that $R(N) = \sum_{d|N} \mu(d) * (N/d)^2$ where $\mu$ denotes the Mobius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, mobius-transformation

I came across the following advanced question in the textbook:

Let $R(N)$ denote the number of ordered pairs $(n, m) \in [N]^2$ such that $n, m, N$ are relatively prime.

I have to show that $R(N) = \sum_{d|N} \mu(d) * (N/d)^2$ where $\mu$ denotes the Mobius function.

I've tried writing the number of ordered pairs as

$$\sum_{m = 1}^N\sum_{n = 1}^N\sum_{d \mid (m,n)}\mu(d)$$ but I have no clue how to proceed.

I am a starter within the subject of discrete mathematics and number theory. Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The textbook is more like a specified collection questions book our professor made. So not a “real” book. I edited the question with something I tried

Comment: You may be struggling because the formula is wrong. Check equality for $N=3$. The correct formula is $$R(N)=\sum_{d=1}^N \mu(d)\left\lfloor \frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor^2$$

Comment: Is there a way you can elaborate it more? I am still struggling with finding the formula

Comment: I might have originally misread your question... Do $m,n$ also need to be relatively prime to $N$? If so, my formula is wrong, but so is yours.

Comment: Yes, $m,n$ need to be relatively prime to $N$.